# python3-statsmodels missing in Software Center

Tags: software-center, python3

Why is there no python3-statsmodels in the Ubuntu Software Center? I can only find python-statsmodels. I am running 14.04 LTS.

Comment: There is no python3-statsmodels package, even for Ubuntu 16.04 or 16.10. Maybe there's a way to install it with `pip`, for example by running `sudo pip3 install statsmodels`? Or you could install it from source: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/install.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer to 'why' is in [Debian Bug 782963](https://bugs.debian.org/782963), April 2015.

The current package maintainers would like some help packaging the Py3 version and maintaining it. Any willing community member can volunteer to help and learn the skills to participate.